# Roslyn Scripting

Tags: c#, roslyn

Hi I want to use Roslyn to scripting in my app. But I have new (September) version and I am confused. I want to execute file with some simply function. 
For example:

```
public int m(){
      return 6;
}
```

I found some articles about it for example [acticle](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/11/16/the-roslyn-scripting-api.aspx). There is some way to do it, but in my version isn't `Session.Create()` 
I want to use it like IronPython scripting

Something like:

```
var scriptEngine = new SciptEngine.ExecuteFile(fileWithFunction);
dynamic d = getFunction(m);
```

or

dynamic d = callFunction(m);

Is it possible or I must use IronPython scripting?

Comment: I don't know anything about Roslyn, but you can use c# as a scripting engine without it. You can use the class CSharpCodeProvider from namespace Microsoft.Csharp to compile an assembly at runtime and invoke methods or create objects from that assembly. See for instance here for an example: http://www.crowsprogramming.com/archives/99

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. But: I want to use it in my Mogre game and my supervisor told me to try to use Roslyn because it is c# compiler written in c# so it could be much more quickly. I don't know if it is true, but if someone know how to do it, so I can test it.

Answer (score 17):

The API hasn't changed significantly since the original CTP that the article was written in. For your scenario:

```
var scriptEngine = new ScriptEngine();
var session = scriptEngine.CreateSession();
session.AddReference("System");
session.AddReference("System.Core");
session.Execute(@"public int m() { return 6; }");

int six = session.Execute<int>("m()");
```